# WSO2 ESB DBLookup mediator query multiple rows

Tags: wso2, mediator, wso2-esb

As it says in the documentation of the DBLookup Mediator it only returns the first row of the query, the other results if they are, were ignored.

I want to know if there is a "best way" to run a query (SELECT * FROM X) that return multiple records and then process them. Now a days we are doing that implementing axis2 services but there is another way using a combination of the mediators provided by wso2 esb to accomplished that requirement??

Thanks in advance.

Santiago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes DBlookup mediator will not return multiple rows. You can use two alternatives.

1) Use WSO2 Data services Server to create a data service and invoke that service from ESB using call out mediator.

2) You can write a class mediator to query data from database and then create a the payload from that and then send that through the sequence.

Comment: Thanks Shelan for the anwser. I think it's a very generic problem, you know why Synapse or WSO2 didn't provide out of the box the option number 2 of your answer? Maybe if the payload of the message (the result of the query is too big) could have some drawbacks in the Message Context of synapse?? Or there's not a problem with that?

Thanks again Santiago.

Comment: Yes. If the result set is too huge then it is a problem to add them to message context. Still this JIRA related to that is in open state https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SYNAPSE-533 as the provided solution is not elegant.

Comment: Yes i see it, thats why i ask you... Thanks a lot for the response Shelan!

Answer (score 3):

To avoid writing another service or setting up a full blown WSO2 Data Services Server to overcome DB Lookup Mediator shortcoming, I extended existing mediator but did not contribute he code back to the community due to the time constraints. Here is the code of updated org.apache.synapse.mediators.db.DBLookupMediator.

Basically, it transforms ResultSet into XML format and sets the result into DB_SEARCH_RESULT property. It probably needs some polishing and testing on race conditions too.

```
package org.apache.synapse.mediators.db;

import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext;
import org.apache.synapse.SynapseException;
import org.apache.synapse.SynapseLog;
import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

/**
 * Simple database table lookup mediator. Designed only for read/lookup
 */
public class DBLookupMediator extends AbstractDBMediator {

    public static final String DB_SEARCH_RESULTS_PROPERTY_NAME = "DB_SEARCH_RESULT";

    protected void processStatement(Statement stmnt, MessageContext msgCtx) {

        SynapseLog synLog = getLog(msgCtx);

        // execute the prepared statement, and extract the first result row and
        // set as message context properties, any results that have been specified
        Connection con = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = getPreparedStatement(stmnt, msgCtx);
            con = ps.getConnection();
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            // convert RS to XML
            String rsXML = convertRSToXML(rs);

            // add result XML to the Message Context
            msgCtx.setProperty(DB_SEARCH_RESULTS_PROPERTY_NAME, rsXML);

            // rollback to the beginning of ResultSet to allow standard processing
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                if (synLog.isTraceOrDebugEnabled()) {
                    synLog.traceOrDebug(
                        "Processing the first row returned : " + stmnt.getRawStatement());
                }

                for (String propName : stmnt.getResultsMap().keySet()) {

                    String columnStr =  stmnt.getResultsMap().get(propName);
                    Object obj;
                    try {
                        int colNum = Integer.parseInt(columnStr);
                        obj = rs.getObject(colNum);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
                        obj = rs.getObject(columnStr);
                    }

                    if (obj != null) {
                        if (synLog.isTraceOrDebugEnabled()) {
                            synLog.traceOrDebug("Column : " + columnStr +
                                    " returned value : " + obj +
                                    " Setting this as the message property : " + propName);
                        }
                        msgCtx.setProperty(propName, obj.toString());
                    } else {
                        if (synLog.isTraceOrDebugEnabled()) {
                            synLog.traceOrDebugWarn("Column : " + columnStr +
                                    " returned null Skip setting message property : " + propName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (synLog.isTraceOrDebugEnabled()) {
                    synLog.traceOrDebug("Statement : "
                        + stmnt.getRawStatement() + " returned 0 rows");
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            handleException("Error executing statement : " + stmnt.getRawStatement() +
                " against DataSource : " + getDSName(), e, msgCtx);
        } finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {}
            }
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
            }
        }
    }

    private String convertRSToXML(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException  {
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        // create XML document
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            throw new SynapseException("Failed to transform Resultset to XML", pce);
        }

        // create Root element
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("table");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        while (rs.next()) {
            // add Record element
            Element recordElement = doc.createElement("record");
            rootElement.appendChild(recordElement);

            for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                String columnValue = rs.getObject(i).toString();

                // add Field element
                Element fieldElement = doc.createElement("field");
                fieldElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(columnValue));

                // set Name attribute to Field element
                Attr nameAttr = doc.createAttribute("name");
                nameAttr.setValue(columnName);
                fieldElement.setAttributeNode(nameAttr);                 

                // add Field to Record
                recordElement.appendChild(fieldElement);                            
            }
        }

        //Output the XML
        String xmlString = null;

        try {
            //set up a transformer
            TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
            trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
            trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

            //create string from XML tree
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            trans.transform(source, result);
            xmlString = sw.toString();       
        } catch (javax.xml.transform.TransformerException te) {
            throw new SynapseException("Failed to transform Resultset to XML", te);
        }

        return xmlString;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't retrieve multiple rows using DBLookUp  mediator. But you can use the Data Services Server(DSS) and create the queries. Then you can invoke them using call mediator or send mediator. In the WSO2 EI , DSS also available. Please see the documentation

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Generating+a+Data+Service
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Exposing+Data+as+a+REST+Resource

Here data can be exposing as a REST(in DSS resource) or SOAP(in DSS operation).

Answer (score -1):

Simply Use the DBSelect Mediator from here https://github.com/ichakios/dbselect-wso2-mediator
easy to use and return JSON result